# How do you pronounce "chasse"?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade-5e, pronunciation

My group just started a new chronicle and we're trying to figure out how to say "chasse" out loud.

> **Chasse**
>
> This Trait describes how well stocked,
> vulnerable, and rich the
> domain is as a hunting ground. One
> dot in Chasse provides the coterie
> with a default hunting Difficulty
> of 6 inside their domain. Each additional
> dot reduces that Difficulty
> by one.
>
> Chasse also refers abstractly
> to the physical size of the domain.

-- v5 corebook, pp. 195 - 196

Comment: French speaker here: this is the french word "hunt", pronounced more or less "shass". Go to Google Translate, input "hunt" in English and you will have the opportunity to hear the word "chasse" by clicking the small speaker below it.

Answer (score 14):

#### Scroll to the bottom for the TL;DR.

Not sure why I went so deep on this, but I hope someone has fun reading it.

---

To figure out pronunciation, we first need to disambiguate what word this "**Chasse**" instance is based on. There seem to be three different words spelled as "**Chasse**", that each have different meanings (though with a fair amount of shared etymology).

#### [Chassé](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chasse#English)

The seems to be the most common version of a word spelled "chasse". This is the formal spelling for a specific Ballet step. In English, it can also be spelled as "sashay" ,although that spelling also seems to carry a slightly more expansive meaning than the French spelling  which seems to be specifically for the dance step.

- Pronounced "shaw-say" based on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chasse#Pronunciation), and my personal experience.
- **This is not a good candidate for the basis of the corebook word as it doesn't really make sense in context.**

---

#### [Châsse](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chasse#Old_French)

This seems to be the least common usage of the word. It's one of the two options presented upon just googling "chasse". It seems to be a semi-archaic word for certain types of reliquary boxes. It is often not spelled with the circumflex over the "a", but I included it here to distinguish it from the other candidates.

- I believe it is pronounced "shass" (rhymes with "mass") based on this [handout](https://www.luc.edu/media/lucedu/luma/pdfs/Reliquary_Chasse.pdf) I stumbled upon.
- **This also does not seem like a good candidate for the basis of the corebook word as it  similarly doesn't really make sense in context.**

---

#### [la Chasse](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chasse#French)

This definition was presented the least readily by google, but seems like the best bet. This is a French word which seems to roughly translate to "The Hunt" (based on the word's usage [here](https://www.connexionfrance.com/French-news/France-hunting-season-to-begin-4-facts-about-la-chasse) and in a few other articles I peeked at).

- Pronounced "shass" (like "mass" in English or "más" in Spanish, but with "sh") based on [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chasse#Pronunciation_4).
- **This looks like the correct candidate as it best matches the hunting related context of the rulebook quote.**

---

### TL;DR

**I think ["shass"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chasse#Pronunciation_4) (like "mass" in English or "más" in Spanish, but with "sh") is probably the "most correct" pronunciation.** The corebook seems to be borrowing the French word "la Chasse", an French idiomatic word for "hunting season".

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Good first answer!

Comment: Improvement suggestion: actually transcribe how it's pronounced, instead of relying on the links for that information.

Comment: French native: La chasse refers to the activity (some may say sport) of hunting. A practitioner is called "un chasseur" (generally masculine, the feminine would be chasseuse) which translates to "a hunter", and will typically "chasse" (from the verb "chasser", 1st group, meaning "to hunt") during "la saison de chasse", that is the hunting season. You correctly identified the pronunciation, `ʃas`: `ʃ` as the "sh" in _sheer_, `as` as in _mass_.

Comment: “Más” and “mass” are not pronounced the same, this answer should be clarified as to which it is.

Comment: To my non-francophone, American English ear, the pronunciation buttons make it sound somewhere between "mass" and "más". I don't think I have that vowel in my dialect of English.

Comment: @Nathan: más and chasse should have the a in father. Mass has a completely different vowel (rhymes with lass, crass.)

Comment: @KRyan: "mass" has a vowel sound that's not quite right, but is otherwise right.  The vowel sound is an "a" in the French "chasse", but part way towards English "cross".  Unless anyone knows a better English word for the vowel sound, by far the best advice is just to listen to a recording of someone pronouncing it.  Perhaps like the last part of "purchase", but with the ss sound more elongated, like in "mass".  If I'm not mangling my linguistics too much, or being dependent on a neutral Canadian English accent.

Comment: Looking at vowel charts, it looks like the "a" in French "chasse" is closer in the mouth to the "a" in English "mass" than the "a" in English "father" although neither English phoneme is quite right. The "â" in French "châsse" is closer to the "a" in English "father". Although what I was looking at was about Parisian French, and it looks like some dialects of French may pronounce those words the same? This is just from a cursory Wikipedia and Wiktionary search, though.

Answer (score 8):

### Chasse probably refers to French La Chasse (The Hunt)

VTM uses some other French origin words, and, I suspect from the context, that they are referring to French 'La Chasse', [pronounced](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&sxsrf=ALeKk01L4u1Shm6Zp0987q9nBKFOaJM_QA%3A1615006805604&ei=VQxDYN63JNW5tAbn8pmoAQ&q=pronounce%20chasse%20french&oq=pronounce%20chasse%20french&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQgAEM0COgcIABBHELADOgQIIxAnOgUIABCRAjoOCC4QsQMQgwEQxwEQowI6CAgAELEDEIMBOgQILhBDOgIIADoICC4QxwEQrwE6BQguELEDOgQIABBDOgcILhCxAxBDOgcIABCxAxBDOgUIABCxAzoKCAAQsQMQRhD5AToHCAAQsQMQCjoHCAAQhwIQFDoGCAAQFhAeOggIABAWEAoQHjoFCCEQoAE6BQghEKsCOgcIIRAKEKABUKmqAViL4QFgzeIBaAhwAngAgAFLiAGBC5IBAjI0mAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCMABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiettSX8ZrvAhXVHM0KHWd5BhUQ4dUDCAw&uact=5) 'shas' according to Google, or /ʃas/, sounding almost like chase but shorter and softer at the start.

Comment: Improvement suggestion: actually transcribe how it's pronounced, instead of relying on the links for that information.

Comment: 'shas' is the transcription, the link is for anyone that wants to look at what I was looking at and/or hear Google pronounce it

Comment: I meant /ʃas/, the transcription of pronunciation, since there is ambiguity between how 'shas' is pronounced between different accents and dialects.

Comment: I see, I had assumed google used that form being unfamiliar with pronunciation guides (and completely unable to read them)

Comment: @vicky_molokh-unsilenceMonica "Transcription" is any visual system of conveying speech. So any written form is a transcription. I may be wrong, but it seems like you want a specific kind of transcription, like IPA. Is that correct?

Comment: @indigochild I have repeatedly seen, in the contexts of explaining words and their sounds, 'spelling' and 'transcription' used side by side, with the former denoting how a word is *written in a language* and the latter for writing down *how it actually sounds* visually (which is useful for languages with non-shallow orthography). But perhaps that usage is not as much of a default in this context than I am used to. But you are right, I was thinking primarily of IPA (though I'd understand if someone picked SAMPA or the like).

Comment: Addendum: 'shas' seemed like an attempt to use a hypothetical spelling to let the readers try to guess at what it sounds like, rather than strictly encoding sounds.

Comment: "/ʃas/, sounding almost like chase" – But the English word "chase" doesn't sound similar to /ʃas/ at all. "Chase" is pronounced /tʃeɪs/, with a different vowel. (You correctly described the initial consonant in /ʃas/ as "shorter and softer").

Comment: Honestly it sounds how I described to my ear. Thankfully, vicky_molokh-unsilenceMonica provided the correct phonetic for people familiar with that style; they can use that (or the Google link with audio) to get correct pronunciation better than I could describe in plain language.